# I am trying to register as an API developer

Tags: uber-api

When I click on the link in the Developer Guide to register my app, this screen is displayed:

[Register App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIA9n.png)

When I click on the link to "confirm my number" I'm taken to my profile screen and there's nothing there to show me how to confirm my number.

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should contact the admin of the website you are registering to.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this isn't a programming question so this isn't the appropriate place for this question. It sounds like are having issues with your Uber account and your Uber account does not have a mobile number confirmed. Here is an Uber help article about confirming mobile numbers:

https://help.uber.com/h/45926204-8f2e-4f14-9c9f-d97c4517fe8a

If you are still having issues, you could post on the Uber developers community forum with your account info and someone should be able to help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/uber-developers